# python threading do not work

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I had write some codes like:

```
import threading
import httplib2
import time


class Download(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, url, location):
        super(Download, self).__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.location = location
        self.http = httplib2.Http()

    def download(self):
        resp, content = self.http.request(self.url)
        with open(self.location, "wb") as f:
            f.write(content)

    def run(self):
        self.download()


p = Download("http://www.wswd.net/testdownloadfiles/1GB.zip","/tmp/1GB.zip")
p.start()
```

It can be worked with Django,returned immediately and download in background ,everything is fine.

but do not work in terminal,like:

```
python test.py
```

It will be start download after sleep 10 minutes.

Why?

Thank you very much!

---

Sorry to make you misunderstand, I had deleted the `time.sleep(10)` line and changed the PNG file to a big EXE file.

It can be returned immediately and download in background with Django.

But it was blocked and wait for download complete when I run with:

```
python test.py
```

in terminal

I don't know why.....

---

Someone deleted the second answer that I am reading.....

Comment: The line `time.sleep(10)` will cause the thread to sleep for ten seconds. If you don't want this, remove this line.

Comment: sorry ,my fault ，that should be then seconds.

Comment: I wrote that line for test.  it do not sleep 10 seconds in background that I want it to ,but can be worked in django......

Answer (score 4):

It does work in the terminal, but the Python process itself must host all threads, so it can't exit before all threads are done running. Here's a visualization:

```
[1]    [2] [4]
 +------+---+
        \
         '-+-----------------------------+
          [3]                           [5]


\                                        /
 '------- Python process lifespan ------'
```

Events:

1. Python starts, runs imports and class definitions
2. Your thread starts
3. Download initiates on secondary thread
4. main thread has nothing more to do, exiting
5. Download finishes, secondary thread exists

The reason it works in Django is because Django's main thread is always busy waiting for more work, but that doesn't mean your threading isn't working.

To solve this and actually download in the background, you can either start python on the terminal with `python yourfile.py &` (notice the ampersand), or you can use [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to spawn a new Python process unattached to the main process, which will continue after the Python started from terminal closes.

P.S.: I'm bad at ASCII art, don't laugh at me.

Comment: No laughing at your ASCII art--it's definitely a useful aid to this question.  Nice job!

Comment: Yes, the ASCII art is easy to understand ~

Comment: @user3323381 Did this answer solve your question? If so, don't forget to click the check button, it marks the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Python process will wait until all non-daemon threads have exited before returning you to the prompt.  If you add `print("Bye!")` to the end of your script, you will see it print but still delay before returning the prompt.  This is because your download thread hasn't completed yet, and Python is waiting for it to finish.  On the other hand, if you created the thread as a daemon thread, the Python process would exit immediately and kill your running thread, leaving you with a partial download--if that, since it'll exit so quickly.

If your hope was to have the code run as a background process, you have a few choices.  First, you don't need a separate thread for that--you can simply run it in the background from your shell, if you're on a Unix style system:

```
python test.py &
```

The `&` says to launch the process in the background.

An alternative, in a Unix environment, is to have the Python code put itself in the background.  I won't go into all the details here, but a good mechanism for writing daemons that run in the background can be found [here](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).

With Django, you didn't have to worry about this since it's a long running process and waits for more work.